# How to Connect to Remote MySQL Server with my C# Application

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to connect my C# application developed in my Standalone PC with my Hosted Linuux MySQL Server. How can i do it.. Is there any server configuration setup or any kind of Remote Connection Permission Setting have to be done? Please help with this..

Comment: you need to allow the mysql server to accept remote connections.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the server where MySQL is at can accept connections.

[Read this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/423233/How-to-Connect-to-MySQL-Using-Csharp) to read how to configure your c# application to connect to MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

The connection string code should like this

`Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;`

You need to allow the remote connection by [this way](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/camilord/connecting-to-remote-mysql-linux-server-using-visual-C-Sharp/)

Answer (score 0):

Mysql has very good documentation how to connect mysql server (local and remote).
It is here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-connectors.html
 And your case may be this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-c/en/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Its Pretty Simple to Implement 
1) Download My Sql Connector From https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.9.html

2) In your C# Project add refrence of  Mysql.Data.Dll

3) use this Connection String
 string connectionString= "SERVER=000.000.000.000;DATABASE=testdb;UID=test;PASSWORD=test123;"
4) use same like this sample code

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL...");
            conn.Open();
            // Perform database operations
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        conn.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
```

or Read this tutorials
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-connection.html